# Rails 4 view Helper: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers

I was upgrading a project from rails 3 to rails 4. When I switched to rails 4, I met this error in logs. But I didnt pass any argument to this method.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
    1: <div id="titles_list">
    2:
    3:   <div id="admin_title_select_group">
    4:     <% table_group = select_table_group %>
    5:     <%= select_tag 'selected_group', options_for_select(table_group, by_default_selected_group) %>
    6:   </div>
    7:
  app/helpers/admin/titles_helper.rb:14:in `select_table_group'
  app/views/admin/titles/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_admin_titles_index_html_erb__3791160006166460542_70179046974220'
  lib/metal/search_store.rb:17:in `call'
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="titles_list">

  <div id="admin_title_select_group">
    <% table_group = select_table_group %>
    <%= select_tag 'selected_group', options_for_select(table_group, by_default_selected_group) %>
  </div>
...
```

Here is my helper methods:

```
module Admin::TitlesHelper

  def select_table_group
    g = [[I18n.t('admin.tpgn.select_group'),0]]
    g += TitleProviderGroupName.all(:order => :name).collect{|t| [ t.name, t.id ]}

  end

  def by_default_selected_group
    if params[:tpgn_id]
      params[:tpgn_id]
    else
      0
    end
  end

end
```

It works well in rails 3. Is there any changes about helper method in rails 4? I didn't find any information about this.

Comment: Which line in `titles_helper.rb` is 14th?

Comment: `g += TitleProviderGroupName.all(:order => :name).collect{|t| [ t.name, t.id ]}`         Ah, thanks your reminder, I thought the problem is Model.all no longer accept argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all) method doesn't take parameters in Rails 4.

```
TitleProviderGroupName.all
```

has to be changed to

```
TitleProviderGroupName.order(:name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I found it :)